# Are those some new symmetries among the Twin Primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

For each pair of Twin Primes $(p_a;p_b)$, the following operation gets applyed:

1. Concatenation of the pair to one real number $R_{ab}$ by using a comma inbetween for separation.
2. Calculating the square of that real number.
3. Decouple the squared real number at the comma back into two integers again.
4. Calculating the sum $S_{ab}$ of those two integers.

Example:

$(p_a;p_b)=(59;61)$

1. $R_{ab}=59,61=61,59.$
2. $R_{ab}^2=(59,61)^2 = 3553,3521$ and $R_{ba}^2=(61,59)^2=3793,3281.$
3. $S_{ab}=3553+3521= 7074 = 3793+3281 = 7074 = S_{ba}. $

I'm looking for any explanation on some results of this operation like below:

[image]

Comment: Remarkable coincidences. I am curious if someone has an explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is specific to twin primes. For example, as well as $(101,103)$, the consecutive odd numbers $(119,121),(545,547),(563,567),(767,769)$ and $(785,787)$ all lead to $826230$; two further pairs $(203,205)$ and $(425,427)$ also lead to $313317$. There are many other examples. That such duplicates appear frequently is interesting.

Comment: I do think it is possible  to use exactly this method to prove that it is mapping those values to a twin Primes counter, I'm however quite sure that this has been long time ago already prooven.